# Android input method doesn't hide after changing with showInputMethodPicker()

Tags: android, android-intent, input, service, keyboard

Hi guys I'm working on an application that increase security when using passwords. I'm working on it since few months and i'd like your help.

I have created a new InputMethodService. I would like to allow access to this input only if the application is open. The application is secured by a password and it closes after a time limit.
In order to know if the application is closed (with finish() ) or not, from the input service, the application send an intent with a boolean (true if it's running, false if it's not) to the InputMethodService.
One of this intent is sent when my app opens, after password's checking :

MyApplication.java:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // Some stuff 
    // Ask password result
    if (requestCode == 10) { 
        if (resultCode == 10) { //password ok
            //Some stuff
            Intent i = new Intent(mContext, PasswordsKeyboard.class);
            i.putExtra("appOpen", true);
            startService(i);
        } else {
            Intent i = new Intent(mContext, PasswordsKeyboard.class);
            i.putExtra("appOpen", false);
            startService(i);
            finish();
        }
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

The last one is sent when the application goes into onDestroy():

MyApplication.java:

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    //Some stuff 
    Intent i = new Intent(mContext, PasswordsKeyboard.class);
    i.putExtra("appOpen", false);
    startService(i);
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

To catch these intents I have a onStartCommand in my InputMethodService  :

MyInputMethodeService.java:

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    boolean myBool= false;
    try {
       myBool= intent.getBooleanExtra("appOpen", false);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    isAppOpen.edit().putBoolean("appOpen", myBool).commit();
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}
```

This code works, but I have a huge problem when using my custom keyboard. When i select my keyboard, it appears and functions normally. The problem comes when I want to make it disappear by using the Space and showInputMethodPicker() method.

The keyboard remains visible on the screen whatever I do. If I select a different keyboard, I see it appears below my custom keyboard. When I use the home or back button, nothing changes, my keyboard is still on the screen. 
If i don't use the showInputMethodPicker() and I use the home button directly, keyboard disappeared normally..

I'm pretty sure their is a problem with my startService() calls because when i comment them, the bug does not occur.

Any help would be appreciated ! Thank you !

Comment: I think that startService() pull up or whatever my input method on the stack but i still can't see what is the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok guys, i found the solution.

That's stupid but I only had to write a stopSelf(); in the onStartCommand() ...

Here's the modified code.

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
boolean myBool= false;
try {
   myBool= intent.getBooleanExtra("appOpen", false);
 } catch (Exception e) {
}
isAppOpen.edit().putBoolean("appOpen", myBool).commit();
stopSelf();
return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}
```